# Create JSON configuration from string using Apache commons configuration

Tags: java, json, apache-commons, apache-commons-config

Is it possible to create a JSON configuration form a `String` in [Apache commons configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) so that I can get some values from it?

For example, if I'd have a `String` containing this configuration, I'd like to be able to convert it into an `org.apache.commons.configuration2.json.JSONConfiguration` so that I can get values from it with the `getX(nodeName)` method (ex.: `config.getInt("sectionA.valueB")` would return 332):

```
{sectionA:{valueA:true, valueB:332}, sectionB:{valueA:124, valueB:"abc"}}
```

Would I have to wrap the string in something such as a `Reader` so that I can use the configuration's `load(Reader)` method? If yes, what would be the shortest and fastest way to do that?

Comment: What is a "JSON configuration"?

Comment: @Aaron Digulla: http://json.org/

Comment: The links doesn't answer my question. Please add some pseudo code to your question to show what you want to do.

Comment: Looks like your question at the end hits it.  Put the string into a StringReader and load it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd much rather use JSON than XML, but short of writing my own JSON shim for the library, I don't see any 'built in' solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate a `FileBasedConfigurationBuilder` using the `JSONConfiguration` class (version >= 2.2):

```
Configurations configs = new Configurations();

FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<JSONConfiguration> builder =
    configs.fileBasedBuilder(JSONConfiguration.class, file);
```

Unfortunately, I have not found a way to get `JSONConfiguration` to pretty print. Overriding the class is not an option as it uses of private fields. It is simple, however, to supply your own class (copy `JSONConfiguration`) and modify the write method:

```
@Override
public void write(final Writer out) throws ConfigurationException, IOException {

    this.mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(out,
        constructMap(this.getNodeModel().getNodeHandler().getRootNode()));

}
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)